# How can I divide the partitions?

Tags: partitioning, gui

I have installed Ubuntu Linux with one partition, but I would like to divide it to two partitions. How can I do this on GUI?

Comment: I think this thread is good http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1219270

Comment: You will need to be a little more specific.  i.e. *how* do you want to divide things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to create important data backup first.

1. Boot Ubuntu Live CD/USB
2. Open GParted
3. Resize down your current parttion to free enough space for the second partition
4. Create new partion at the free space you've made

*(Please, note if more details required.)*

Comment: But then he would have a second partition that is NOT automounted into the file system. Is that what he really wants or does he just wish to outsource e.g. the /home folder onto a separate partition which would not affect the file system?

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup

1. Boot into GParted live session
2. Divide your partition as you want to do by resizing it

Kindly click the tick beneath the down arrow because this would increase my reutation as well as yours (Please do this if my answer is useful)